# module not found error problem when trying to import from another folder

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have this folder structure:

```
--test
    first.py
    --numpad
          second.py
          third.py
```

in the first.py i have this line of code:

```
from numpad import second
```

and in the second.py file i have this:

```
import third
```

but in the test folder when i run

```
python first.py
```

i get this error message:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'third'**

note: i have also tried adding `__init__.py` to my numpad folder but it didnt work

Comment: are you really trying to `import second` in second.py, or is that supposed to be `import third`?

Comment: @arne yes you are right,i edited ,thanks

Comment: Either way, the import probably doesn't work because the python interpreter doesn't know that `numpad` is supposed to be a python module. You can tell it that it is one by adding an empty `__init__.py` file into the `numpad` folder.

Comment: @arne i did that but didnt work, i added ```__init__.py``` in numpad folder but didnt work

Comment: Did you add `__init__.py` or `init.py`? There's a difference. But in that case, you should get an error saying `No module named numpad`

Comment: @nightgaunt no i added ```__init__.py``` but it didn't  work. have you tested this yourself? does it work this way?

Comment: I just did and it works splendidly. In your first.py add `print(sys.path)` before imports and share the output

Comment: @mhmighani right, I overlooked the python3.6 tag, the `__init__.py` stuff is python2. Next thing to try would be to do an explicitly local import for `third`, i.e. `from . import third`. Since your interpreter runs at a level where `third` is not visible, this might be necessary

Comment: @Arne stack overflow continues to amaze me. I didn't know init is not required in python3.6. Thanks for the info

Comment: @nightgaunt Yeah, for some reason it's not very well known. It was introduced as [pep 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the python interpreter is started within `test`, that's where it looks for imports. You can learn about pythons's search behavior for imports through [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), if you're interested in the details.

To solve your problem, there are a bunch of ways to do it, the best one depending on how you plan to use your code. If you plan to write a library, it might make sense to [package it](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which would give you access to a global namespace that you can use.

But if you just want it to work right now, and only ever are going to run the interpreter from the same place (i.e. your `test` folder), defining the `third` file as a local one should do it:

**second.py**

```py
from . import third
```

**third.py**

```py
print('third here, not an import error')
```

This works for me:

```sh
~/test$ tree . 
.
├── first.py
└── numpad
    ├── second.py
    └── third.py
~/test$ python3.6 first.py
third here, not an import error
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on this, but I'm pretty sure you'd have to set up your environment variable to look in that specific folder. Which would be way more of a hassle than just adding your homemade modules to your default modules folder.

Comment: Current folder is usually a path where python looks for modules. You can verify this using `print(sys.path)`

Comment: Hmmm. I never actually knew that!  For whatever reason, mine doesn't. Probably one of my coworkers screwing with the path variable. Pretty ironic lol